# change store into 2 store

Tags: magento2

Client already using Magento store,

Now they are going to introduce new product line,
How can we generate new store under same platform.

Home Page have some Company info and both link for different store( i.e Men & Women )

When user is on Men section, all the products and checkout will be only for Men.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new store from magento 2 admin panel itself.

**Logged in to you magento 2 admin panel**

**Click on menu stores->all stores ->Our there you will see the options to create a store.**

**You can also choose which default category you would like to select as root directory**

You can keep the same theme - with little twiks on the new store

For more details refer below links -

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-a-new-store-view-magento-2.html

http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-in-magento2/

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html

Comment: can we use 2 difference theme for different stores?

Comment: Yes We can use it for the same !